# how to change class member visibility?

Tags: c#

I have a class with a combobox inside. I want to add items to this combobox from a different class, but I cannot see it.
I've instantiated the class (with the combobox) using 'new', i.e.:

```
check_reg _check_reg = new check_reg();
```

but in my second class I see only the 
`_form1.Choose_Quar_SelectedIndexChanged` paramter, which is the handler shown when I double click the combo box in the form, it does not help me add the items.

I'm sure it's a basic question... so please help me with it.
Thx!

Comment: Show relevant code. If you mean "form" or "control" instead of "class", see [How to: Use the Modifiers and GenerateMember Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You can change the modifier to the combobox from private to public or protected if the new class inherits from your base class.

Comment: How do I do that, @faby?

Comment: @roy.me I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you can create a public instance method inside the class "check_reg" to add items to the combobox.

Something like this:

```
public void AddItem(ListItem li)
{
    ddl.Items.Add(li);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
check_reg _check_reg = new check_reg();
_check_reg.AddItem(new ListItem("Text", "Value"));
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, but ListItem is not recognized... this is not a webpage project or something, just a GUI application. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that a Windows Form project?

Comment: Yes. It's a Windows Form Project.

Comment: Well, the "Add" method accept an "object". So, just try with a string value.

Comment: Ok, got it now! Finally, Now I understand it and it is working... At last. Thank you very very much. :o)

Answer (score 1):

You should use your combobox as a property of your class with public modifier

So first thing go to your YourPage.designer.cs and remove the declaration of the combobox e shift it to the code behind of the page.

change from

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl combobox;
```

to

```
public global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl combobox;
```

after this you will be able to see the combobox as a public property of the class where it is declared